# Elements not removed from Set

Tags: java, iterator, set

I have a `TreeSet` with a comparator:

```
private final TreeSet<TimedTask> sortedEvents;

public TimedUpdatableTaskList(){
    Comparator<TimedTask> comparator = new TimedTaskComparator();
    sortedEvents = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
}
```

The class implements a method to add elements to the set:

```
public void add(TimedTask task) {
    synchronized (sortedEvents) {
        sortedEvents.add(task);
        log.info("Add task {}:{}", task.getClass().getName(), task);
    }
}
```

The `TimedTask`s added are like this:

```
class AIRepairTask extends TimedTask {

    private AsyncEventBus clientServerEventBus;

    private final IShip ship;
    private final IShipyard shipyard;

    public AIRepairTask(LocalDateTime executionTime, IShip ship, IShipyard shipyard) {
        super();
        setExecutionTime(executionTime);
        this.ship = ship;
        this.shipyard = shipyard;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ship.repair();
        shipyard.removeCompletedRepair(ship);
        ship.setAvailable(true);
        clientServerEventBus.post(new RepairFinishedEvent(ship));
    }
}
```

And then there is a method that iterates over the elements and eventually removes them:

```
public void handleClockTick(ClockTick event) {
    LocalDateTime now = date.getCurrentDate();
    int nbHandledTasks = 0;
    synchronized (sortedEvents) {
        int initialSize = sortedEvents.size();
        boolean moreEvents = true;
        while(moreEvents && !sortedEvents.isEmpty()) {
            TimedTask task = sortedEvents.first();
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(task.getExecutionTime(), "The exectution time of the task may not be null");
            if (task.getExecutionTime().isBefore(now)) {
                try {
                    task.run();
                    boolean removed = sortedEvents.remove(task);
                    Preconditions.checkArgument(removed, "The Task "+task+" was not removed.");
                    nbHandledTasks++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            } else {
                moreEvents = false;
            }
        }
        Preconditions.checkArgument(initialSize - nbHandledTasks == sortedEvents.size(), "List size did not become smaller: initial size "+initialSize+", handled tasks "+nbHandledTasks+", actual list size: "+sortedEvents.size());
    }
}
```

As the essential parts are wrapped in a synchronized block, the set should not change while iterating over the elements.

Given that there are no exceptions in the `try` block, the precondition check at the end, should never fail, but that is exactly what happens:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: List size did not become smaller: initial size 41, handled tasks 2, actual list size: 41
```

How can this happen?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. My guess is that task.run() adds a task to the events.

Comment: You recorded `initialSize` before you entered the `synchronized` block. It's possible that the size of `sortedEvents` increased after `initialSize` and before `synchronized` block.

Comment: @srikfreak moving `initialSize` into the `synchronized` block does not change a thing. @JBNizet: Added a example `TimedTask` and logging to the add methods, so that I can verify that no tasks were added.

Comment: And what happens if you remove `task.run()`?

Comment: If you do a simple test (without any concurrency involved) that just adds a task to `sortedEvents` and then removes it does it work? I suspect you did not define `equals` and/or `TaskTimeComparator` correctly.

Comment: Try logging the list size every time you remove a task.

Comment: As @JBNizet suspected, there were some `TimedTask` implementations that add one new entry to the list.

Comment: Can you share your implementation of TimedTaskComparator. That seems to have some issue.